# How to create a vector of Templates?

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector

Im trying to build a vector of type template but keep getting an error

```
 template<class T>
 struct s{

    T val;

    public:
        s(T a)
        {
            val = a;
        };

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const T& a);
 };

 template <typename T>
 ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const T& a){
     return os << a.val;
 }

int main()
{
    s <double> names(4) ;
    s <int> figure(7);
    s <string> word();
    s <vector<int>*> arrays();
    cout << names << endl;
    cout << figure << endl;
    cout << arrays << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I keep receiving the same error -

```
request for member 'val' in 'a', which is of non-class type 's<std::vector<int>*>()'|
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: For starters, your struct doesn't have a default constructor. And you should pass the argument by const reference.

Comment: Which arguments? the ones into the data types initialization?

Answer (score 2):

```
s <vector<int>*> arrays();
```

This does not instantiate an object, it declares a function that returns `s<vector<int>*>`, and as a consequence:

```
cout << arrays << endl;
```

Tries to print out a function pointer by instantiating your templated `operator<<`:

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const T& a){
    return os << a.val;
}
```

with:

```
T = s<vector<int>*>(*)();
```

and so, a pointer to function `a` does not have the `.val` field which triggers the error.

Comment: OK so I removed the parenthesis after arrays. Therefore it would now be a vector<int> of type s if I'm not mistaken? And if I wanted to implement a get() function which would return val, how would I go about this? Thanks for the help guys, it clarified things up

Comment: @user3504476: `T& get() { return val; }   const T& get() const { return val; }`, and to be precise you now have `T = std::vector<int>*`, so `val` is a pointer to vector of ints

Comment: It gives me an error that val was not declared within the scope

Comment: @user3504476: put this declarations inside `struct s`: [link here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9df7d3939b0a0a48)

Comment: OK works like a gem. One last question if you don't mind. If I wanted to implement a set function, would I then do it in the same manner as get but instead allow a parameter? and then set val to that value?

Comment: @user3504476: yes, but for `get` I added overload for `const` context, for `set` methods just use the one without `const`

Comment: `T& set(s<T>){ return val = s<T>;};` ? @Piotr S.

Comment: `void set(const T& t) { val = t; }`

Answer (score 2):

```
s <vector<int>*> arrays();
```

Declares a function named `arrays` taking no arguments and returning a `s<vector<int>*>`. Remove the redundant parentheses or replace them with `{}` for C++11. Of course, your `s` doesn't support default construction, so you need to give it a default constructor - which can be as simple as giving the constructor a default argument:

```
    s(T a = T())
    {
        val = a;
    }
```

and it's better to use the member initialization list instead of assignment and take a const ref instead of by value, since `T` can be large:

```
    s(const T& a = T()) : val(a) { }
```

In C++11, you should take by value and *move* `a` into `val` instead:

```
     s(T a = T()) : val(std::move(a)) { }
```

Also,

```
 template <typename T>
 ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const T& a){
     return os << a.val;
 }
```

would match everything under the sun. Better to match `s` only:

```
 template <typename T>
 ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const s<T>& a){
     return os << a.val;
 }
```

Finally,

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const T& a);
```

befriends (and declares) a simple function rather than a function template. To befriend the template `operator <<` as modified above:

```
    template <typename U>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const s<U>& a);
```

Or even better, remove the template operator and define the friend function inline (inside the class definition) instead:

```
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const s<T>& a){
        return os << a.val;
    }
```

This is more compact, and also limits friendship to the matching version of `operator <<`, rather than all instantiations of the template.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6867b8b536b37298).

Answer (score 1):

The whole problem is that this

```
ClassName InstanceName();
```

is not creating an instance of `ClassName` using default constructor, but declares a function. In order to do what you wanted (and I presume that is to create instances with default constructors) use syntax

```
ClassName InstanceName;
```

So, in order to fix your errors, change

```
s <string> word();
s <vector<int>*> arrays();
```

to

```
s <string> word;
s <vector<int>*> arrays;
```

and add a [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) to your class `s`.

Comment: Ok I've done that now. The vector I've created now doesn't seem to have the push_back capability? Do I have to assign it a size or what?

Comment: The reason for that completely depends on your implementation.

Comment: How would I add values to this vector?

Comment: I think, the possibility of adding elements itself must be OK. The question is: have you actually created a vector or not? Your class contains only a pointer to a vector — initially, you have no vector at all; so there is no surprise that you can't add new elements if you have no vector.

Comment: So if I deference it then it would become a normal vector?

Comment: Well, formally yes, but if you have not allocated it beforehand, it will contain only garbage, at won't work correctly. Before dereferencing something, be sure that you've allocated it. Take a look here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/.